# How to play music from my computer on iPhone (without iTunes)?

Tags: windows, music

How can I play music that resides my computer on my iPhone (plugged in to my stereo)? I am at home, they are on the same wifi network. The computer runs Windows 7.

I tried iTunes's sharing feature and my computer's "library" was listed on the phone, but  when I select it, the symbol spins for a minute then gives up. Once it did work, but it only listed about a hundred songs (of tens of thousands). I don't know why.

I'd like to choose the music from the iPhone.

Edit: I have much more music than disk space on my iPhone, so I can't copy it all.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: You explicitly are looking for a non-iTunes/Home Sharing solution because it doesn't seem to work reliable enough in your case. Have you thought about asking a separate question to get help in resolving these issues?

Comment: iTunes is frustratingly slow - it takes a minute to open and then when I type anything it freezes for several seconds.

Comment: If you want help on that, please ask a new question.

Comment: That's just how iTunes is (other apps on my computer run fine). That's why everyone on Windows loathes iTunes. Presumably the Mac experience is better.

Comment: Yeah, iTunes (aka the Excel Spreadsheet of music apps) on my PC is pretty shoddy. It's gotten better since 11, but I have issues with it.

Comment: I'm currently using an iPod Touch in basically this exact way: streaming music through iTunes Home Sharing. The "incomplete library" is a known issue, but logging out of and then back into Home Sharing on the iOS device brings the full contents of the Mac back into view — at least until the problem resurfaces.

Answer (score 4):

You want a DNLA streaming app for your iPhone, which can play a music library via a DLNA server running on your PC.

For the PC side, google "windows DLNA server" will get you current choices, but at this time there are [Plex](http://www.plexapp.com/), [Tversity](http://tversity.com/), and [Twonky](http://www.twonky.com/products/twonkywindows/default.aspx)

On the iPhone side, look at apps like [Media:connect](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/media-connect-for-dlna-upnp/id335036887?mt=8). There are summaries of current choices online, like this one: http://blog.dreamcss.com/iphone/dlna-streaming-apps-for-iphone/

Comment: +1 for DLNA
for PC you can use XBMC, Windows Media Player, Serviio For iPhone I'd recommend DLNA clients - ArkMC or 8Player

Answer (score 2):

I can't offer you another option, but I have run into the sharing issue as well. Occasionally my iPhone will connect very slowly and not show my entire library.

The fix that has always worked for me, is to remove and then reset the home sharing Apple ID from the iPhone Music settings. This seems to reset everything to how it should be and has solved my issue in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I never thought to do this because I have an iPod that I generally use for music but it sounds interesting. I might try this app when I get home.

http://wifi2hifi.cleverandson.com/
It's 3.99 but it supposedly works well, you need to download something on your computer for it to work; it looks like it only supports up to 10.6 but maybe you can find more information about that; it's likely compatible with newer versions. Also, the reviews said there is a few seconds of lag but as long as you don't have the sound on your computer or watching video it shouldn't be a problem.

You could also upload your music to music.google.com and stream that way. I haven't used it in a while though so I don't know how well it works anymore. At the time there was no app for it either so you had to do it through your phone's browser.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp). It's free and can stream to almost any device with a web browser. There's also and native iPhone client (and native clients for several other platforms). It can stream a stand alone music library or an existing iTunes library.

It's pretty easy to setup. Basically just run the installer and point it to your music folder.

I've been using it for a few years and it works great.

Comment: +1 for this solution. You can listen to your music anywhere you have a web browser, it's completely format-agnostic, you can share it with others.  I wrote a Subsonic app that runs on iOS in fact. (Sonic Stream in the app store.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one has suggested the Plex Media Server.   Basically you have the Plex Media Server running on your PC (either Mac, Windows, Linux) and can play media from your iPhone with their iPhone/iPad app.

You can even set it up so you can play music/watch videos when you are not at home.  They will stream from your home PC.

Take a look at http://www.plexapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Tonido](http://www.tonido.com/tonidodesktop/). It does a lot more than music streaming, but it looks like it would fill your desired role well. You run a server component on your computer, and there's an [iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tonido-file-access-music-video/id388726418?mt=8) for playback. If you want you can even access your music collection when you're not on your home network.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [StreamToMe](http://projectswithlove.com/streamtome) (iOS & Mac App) and [ServeToMe](http://projectswithlove.com/streamtome/servetome.html) (Windows & Mac). I do believe it works over the internet as well, but am not sure as I haven't used it in quite a while. It allows you to Play Music, Videos and Photos.

Answer (score -1):

You can try WiFi2HiFi , works great..
Just download the app onto your iPhone and PC or Mac .

On Itunes : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wifi2hifi/id417409424

Mac or PC : http://www.wifi2hifi.com/

Well Apple also has a solution , Airport Express but costs 99 $ .